# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. android 7

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > java.io.IOException: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify th
  >   e proper '-injars' options?
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Any more details please, like environment, cordova cli and cordova-android versions?

Comment: cordova version 8.0.0 , android 7.1.0